# Mongoose - Updating a referenced Document when saving

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

If I have a Schema which has an Array of references to another Schema, is there a way I can update both Documents with one endpoint?

This is my Schema:

```
CompanySchema = new Schema({
  addresses: [{
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Address'
  }]
});
```

I want to send a `Company` with the full `Address` object to `/companies/:id/edit`. With this endpoint, I want to edit attributes on `Company` and `Address` at the same time.

In `Rails` you can use something like nested attributes to do one big `UPDATE` call, and it will update the `Company` **and** update or add the `Address` as well.

Any idea how would you do this in `Mongoose`?

Answer (score 2):

Cascade saves are not natively supported in `Mongoose` ([issue](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/2418#issuecomment-61795795)).

But there are plugins (example: [cascading-relations](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cascading-relations)) that implement this behavior on nested [populate objects](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html).

Take in mind that mongodb is [**not** a fully transactional database](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/write-operations-atomicity/), and the "big save" is achieved with various insert()/update() op calls and you (or the plugin) have to handle errors and rollback.

Example of cascade save:

```
company.save()
  .then(() => Promise.all(company.addresses.map(address => {
    /* update fkeys if needed */
    return address.save()
    }))
  .catch(err => console.error('something went wrong...', err))
```

Comment: Given that this is in the very early stages of development, if I want to do something like this, then it makes sense to replace `Mongoose` or even `MongoDB` in order to achieve this? It would be ideal to have a single page where I can update a Company and its Address, so in this case it's better to use a different DB or re-structure my Models right?

Comment: If you *really* need to save it in a _transaction_ to achieve a strong consistency, Is better to use a RDBMS engine. But I think is not your case, and you can succefull handle it with a custom cascade save logic.

Comment: I see, yep, I looked at the cascading-relations library that you mentioned but the docs for that had me very lost to be honest and didn't know where to start to even attempt this logic. So not sure which direction to go with. From what I can tell I would add `$through` to my `Address`, but I'm not sure what to do from there. For example, I would like to pass my full `Company` object into the `create` endpoint or `update` endpoint and save/update the relevant `Address`

Comment: If your logic is simple you can implement it you self. I added an example (not tested) using builtin promises support in mongoose.

Comment: Will give it a go, should be as simple as just added $through and applying the save logic you mentioned?

Comment: In your example, wouldn't `company.save()` fail because I am passing in a Company which has the full Address as `company.address` instead of an `_id`?

Comment: In the example I suppose that `addresses` are previously populated using  `Company.findOne({ ... }).populate('addresses').exec(...)`

Comment: Interesting, so this would work for an update as mentioned in the OP, but would not work when creating a `create` function? I was wandering if with this library it would also be possible to pass in a `Company` with full `Address` and save both of them.

Comment: Never mind anyway, seems that the plugin is outdated and doesn't work with the latest mongoose version from what I can tell. Back to the drawing board for me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132407/discussion-between-dario-and-germainelol).